# Connecting two tables based on primary keys using python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have 100 tables, where a primary key is present in each table with the name IDname. I can do the relationship in phpmyadmin using designer. But doing this with 100 tables is a bit complicated. I created and inserted the data using python. I was hoping to create the relationship using python. Could you please help. I searched and found a few results related to SQLAlchmey, but didn't know how to use it or was even correct.

Scripts I used:

```
import MySQLdb

db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="graphdata")

cur=db.cursor()



c1=''' CREATE TABLE performance_target (schedule VARCHAR(30), class VARCHAR(30),idname VARCHAR(100),id VARCHAR(30), perform_target VARCHAR(30),PRIMARY KEY (idname)) '''


cur.execute(c1)

db.commit()
```